# Is this Anti-symmetric or not?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

The textbook question is:

Let $P$ be the set of all people in the world and define a relation $R$ on $P$ as follows: For all
$x, y ∈P, xRy ⇔ x$ is no older than $y$.
Is R antisymmetric? Prove or give a counterexample.

I thought it would be anti-symmetric but the textbook says it is not, but does not provide a counter example.

My attempt to solve this logically:
If $x$ is no older than $y$ and $y$ is no older than $x$ then $x = y$
thinking about it logically, $x$ and $y$ have to be the same age. If $x = 20$ and $y = 30$ then $yRx$ would not be in the relation as it is older than $x$, making the $xRy$ and $yRx$ false, but the whole statement true.

So if we want to have a $xRy$ and $yRx$ relation $x$ must be the same age $y$ making the definition of anti-symmetry true.

Comment: @user2661923, what you’re talking about is symmetry, not antisymmetry.

Comment: For the "older" in $x\mathrel R y$, is $x$ no "older" than $y$ _with $x$ as the observer_? Then can $y$ be no "older" than $x$ with $y$ as the observer at the same instant? But is there even a same instant for all the $P$?

Comment: @peterwhy, what do you mean by introducing the notion of observers? Why do you introduce distinct times for the elements of $P$?

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum As time is relative, I would like clarification on what "older" mean, and hence to decide whether $x\mathrel R y$ may be antisymmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding of the meaning of antisymmetry. You are right that their **ages** are the same, but what antisymmetry would mean for this relation is that for individuals $x$ and $y$, if $x$’s age doesn’t exceed $y$’s age and $y$’s age doesn’t exceed $x$’s, then $x$ and $y$ are actually the same person.

Antisymmetry of a relation $R$ means that the only way one can have both $x R y$ and $y R x$ is if $x$ **is** $y$. Or, said slightly differently, if $x$ and $y$ are distinct, then at most one of $x R y$ and $y R x$ can be true.

Comment: The question is about anti-symmetry, not anti-transitivity.  (Though your argument seems to be about anti-symmetry, so it is difficult to follow what your intention is.)

Comment: @XanderHenderson, oops! You’re right.  Fixed now.

Comment: I see thanks, I was thinking only about the ages and not the people instead. Thanks for the help.